# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to read data from one sheet of excel file and write to other sheet of same excel file.I have tried this :

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("E:\\excel\\input.xlsx"));
            //Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
            //Get first/desired sheet from the workbook
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            //Iterate through each rows one by one
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
            while (rowIterator.hasNext()) 
            {
                Row row = rowIterator.next();
                //For each row, iterate through all the columns
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) 
                {
                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                    //Check the cell type and format accordingly
                    switch (cell.getCellType()) 
                    {
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        System.out.print((int)cell.getNumericCellValue()+ "       ");
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue());
                        break;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
            file.close();
            CreationHelper createHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
            XSSFSheet newSheet = workbook.createSheet("new sheet");
            // Create a row and put some cells in it. Rows are 0 based.
            Row row = newSheet.createRow((short)0);
            // Create a cell and put a value in it.
            Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
            cell.setCellValue(1);
            // Or do it on one line.
            row.createCell(1).setCellValue(1.2);
            row.createCell(2).setCellValue(
                    createHelper.createRichTextString("This is a string"));
            row.createCell(3).setCellValue(true);
            System.out.println("writing to file");
            // Write the output to a file
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(new File("E:\\excel\\input.xlsx"));
            workbook.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.close();
```

I have successfully read data from excel sheet But I am getting exception while writing in new sheet given below

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\excel\input.xlsx (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process)
```

Comment: You are writing to the same file you are reading from without closing it, perhaps try to output to another file ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will happen when you are trying to execute this program while the "input.xlsx" file is already opened by another application.

Please close any instance of MS Excel and try to run it again

Comment: always forget about the out of the box option

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess but XSSFWorkbook should be implementing Closeable thus it has a .close() that should be called.
Maybe the file result still in use because of that? 
You are probably going to need a middle step there: write to a new file, close the XSSFWorkbook and then copy the new file on the old one that you want to write on

Comment: Called close method of XSSFWorkbook  but still getting  same exception.